# Trying to use reflection to find the first Int32 property of a class

Tags: .net, reflection, int

I'm trying to find the **first property of a class** that is an `Integer` .. and get it's value.

So i've got the following code .. which always returns false:

```
foreach(var property in type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
    BindingFlags.Instance))
{
    var someType = property.PropertyType is int; // Always false.
}
```

Why is this / what did I do wrong. This should be really simple :(

/me is having a bad day ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the test to:

```
var firstInt32Property = property.PropertyType == typeof(int);
```

This is necessary because the property's *property-type* is itself not an integer: it is a`System.Type`object that (loosely) represents what type the property-getter returns / property-setter accepts. On the other hand, *invoking* the property getter on an instance of the containing-type will produce an actual integer.

Here's a way to use LINQ instead of the `foreach` loop:

```
var firstInt32Property = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                             .First(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(int));
```

(This will throw an exception if no such property exists.)

---

To retrieve the value of the property from an instance of the containing type:

```
int value = (int)firstInt32Property.GetValue(myObj, null);
```

This will of course fail if the 'first' `Int32` property happens to be an indexer or indeed if it simply doesn't have a getter. You could filter such properties out on the original query if such scenarios are likely.

---

Also note that this code is of limited use because the idea of 'the first property of a class that is an integer' is a little bit suspect. From[`Type.GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx):

> The `GetProperties`method does not
>   return properties in a particular
>   order, such as alphabetical or
>   declaration order. Your code must not
>   depend on the order in which
>   properties are returned, because that
>   order varies.

Comment: You can use == instead of .Equals here, as Type objects are unique for a particular type. Not a criticism - your code will work, of course - I just find == easier to read.

Comment: Hmm.. no idea how I define the first property. I mean, some classes have an `int` as their first property for stuff. I would really want to create an `Interface` which means I can easily grab the property i'm after for any instance that implements that interface .. but I sorta can't do that here. Anyways, i'm not phased about grabbing the `wrong` int property, actually. This is just for some R&D stuff.

Comment: +1 exactly, what's in PropertyType is not an instance of int, is an instance of System.Type.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Thank you, sir. You're right about the readability, updated.